# Android: onActivityResult Intent is null when activity get started through the browser-link

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, android-activity

I'd like to implement a plugin for my Cordova/Ionic Android application.
I have these two main files in the plugin:

**1. MyPlugin.java** Which will be called through an Ionic (Ionic 3, Angular 5) application.

**2. BrowserLinkActivity.java** Is responsible for starting a browser and getting data back from the browser.

**MyPlugin.java :**

The plugin will start the `BrowserLinkActivity` with these lines of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, BrowserLinkActivity.class);
cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Which accordingly, the `onActivityResult` is overridden in the plugin:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 // The data parameter is always null
}
```

Here is the activity. The browser Intent will start in `BrowserLinkActivity` activity `onCreate`.

**BrowserLinkActivity.java :**

```
public class BrowserLinkActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    if (data == null){

      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "The website URL");

      browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | 
                Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

      startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
    else { // Activity has started through the browser-link
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();             
        returnIntent.putExtra("Key","Something");

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

I have defined the `plugin.xml` file like below:

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
    <activity android:name="cordova.plugin.mycustomplugin.BrowserLinkActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTask" android:noHistory="true">

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="MyHost.COM" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</config-file>
```

However, the problem is that when the activity gets called from browser-link, the setResult method doesn't work and `Intent` parameter in `onActivityResult` is always `NULL` (and the requestCode is `RESULT_CANCELED`, too).

How could I prevent `browser-link` from starting/creating a new Instance of `BrowserLinkActivity` activity? (which I think is the main reason that causes `setResult` not works properly).

**Note:** I've already added `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to the `browserIntent` and added `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for the `BrowserLinkActivity` in the `plugin.xml` but still doesn't working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your manifest? Please let me know if you get any result.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Thanks. I edited the question. I've already added that in `plugin.xml` for `BrowserLinkActivity` activity. is that right place to put this option?

Comment: So does it work?

Comment: @ReazMurshed Unfortunately doesn't work. I've also overridden the `onNewIntent` method but it doesn't get called.

Comment: @ReazMurshed The problem solved by removing `android:noHistory="true"` from the `plugin.xml` and adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flags for starting `BrowserLinkActivity` activity. Please post these two tips so I then check that as the answer.

Comment: Hello Payan, thank you for your kind concern. However, I just have pointed out some issues that you could consider looking into. I think, it would be better if you could answer the question yourself and mark that as correct, as you have solved the problem. :)

Comment: @ReazMurshed Hello, dear Reaz. Thank you but your point about singleTask launch mode really informed me about the importance of all added flags. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, then. I am writing that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had suggested earlier to set the `launchMode` to `SingleTask` for `BrowserLinkActivity`.

However, later the author of the question found that removing `android:noHistory="true"` from the `plugin.xml` and lanching the `BrowserLinkActivity` activity with these two intent flags (i.e. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`) worked in this case and the result was set back perfectly.

Hope that helps other developers in future.